# GUI Hosts File Editor for Windows

Tags: windows, gratis, gui, networking

I've become quite tired of manually editing my windows hosts file (c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts). I would like a GUI editor that could make life easier when adding domain entries to this file. My requirements are,

- Gratis
- Compatible with Windows 10
- GUI easy to use interface

Some features that are not required but preferred are,

- Import/Export configurations
- Filters for showing/hiding commented files

Comment: I've changed a tag from Windows-10 to Windows because editing a hosts file in Windows 10 has the same requirements as performing this action in previous versions of Windows. If I am in error, please let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The program I currently use is called HostsFileEditor. It is open source available on GitHub. It meets all my required and preferred requirements. It also knows to remove default comments made by windows itself and has a nice auto-ping feature.

## [Hosts File Editor](https://scottlerch.github.io/HostsFileEditor/)

> Easily edit and manage the hosts file for your Windows PC.
>
> [image: Main editor screen with archive visible]